# How to calculate a quaternion rotation between 2 vectors with a specific final up vector?

Tags: mathematics, rotation, quaternion, orientation

I know you can calculate the quaternion rotation between 2 vectors with something like this after all the optimizations:

```
quat quat::fromtwovectors(vec3 u, vec3 v) {
    vec3 w = cross(u, v); 
    quat q = quat(dot(u, v), w.x, w.y, w.z); 
    q.w += q.magnitude(); 
    return normalize(q);
}
```

However, this returns the shortest quaternion rotation between vec u and vec v. Is there a way to calculate a quaternion rotation between orientation A (with a dir vector and up vector ) and orientation B?

something like

```
quat quat::from_two_orientations(vec3 u_dir, vec3 u_up, vec3 v_dir, vec3 v_up)
```